# Is there any harm in changing the label of a partition or drive?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, label

Sometimes I want to avoid those auto-generated displayed names such as `59 GB Volume` which gets mounted an auto-generated (and to me, "gibberish") path such as `/media/andreas/54F85300F852DFB2`.

Is there any harm in re-naming a partition or USB drive that contains data or has been in use for a while?

For instance, will (re)labeling a Windows partition prevent it from booting? Or will a different label mess up encryption? Will you have to edit any of the auto-generated lines in `fstab` to make sure the Unix-based system still mounts those previously used drives in the same way?

Comment: No; Changing the label of a drive will not prevent Windows from booting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory there might be software around that checks the label and acts depending on the result. But I have yet to come across anything like it.

**Old history**
*On the old AmigaOS, the disk label/name was used in a manner similar to a 'mount point' - in the meaning that access to a named device made the OS actually REQUEST the user to insert of a Volume with that specific name, unless it already was defined.

...

`Assign Label_Name: Any_Present_Directory` typed at the AmigaDOS shell prompt would make the volume Label_Name: be available, more options were available making the use of a PATH-variable obsolete.*